# multi select statement not getting executed

Tags: sql

```
select  
    ((Select 
          [Project Name], count(*) as 'PP_Constuction'
      from 
          [dbo].[EriSite_Executive_Report] 
      where 
          [Planning Object Name] = 'Construction Start'  
          and Status like 'Pending Predecessors' 
      group by
         [Project Name]), 
     (Select 
          [Project Name], count(*) as 'RTS_Constuction'
      from 
          [dbo].[EriSite_Executive_Report] 
      where 
          [Planning Object Name] = 'Construction Start'  
          and Status like 'Ready%' 
      group by   
          [Project Name]), 
     (Select 
          [Project Name], count(*) as 'Comple_Constuction' 
      from 
          [dbo].[EriSite_Executive_Report] 
      where 
          [Planning Object Name] = 'Construction Start'  
          and Status like 'Completed' 
      group by 
          [Project Name])
 )
```

I need Project Name and count based upon some condition including header. But it is giving issue. I want output some thing like below

```
 Project Name  PP_Constuction RTS_Constuction   Comple_Constuction
```

Comment: what is your expected output and also your question is not clear. "But it is giving issue." - what the issue is?

Comment: Added my expected output headers. Not able to execute the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
Select 
    [Project Name], 
    count(case when [Planning Object Name] 
    ='Construction Start'  and Status like 'Pending Predecessors' then 1 end) as 'PP_Constuction',
    count(case when [Planning Object Name] 
    ='Construction Start'  and Status like 'Ready%' then 1 end) as 'RTS_Constuction',
    count(case when [Planning Object Name] 
    ='Construction Start'  then 1 end) as 'Comple_Constuction'
from [dbo].[EriSite_Executive_Report]  
group by [Project Name]
```

Comment: Union all will give me only 2 headers project name and PP_Constuction. I want 4 headers like shown in my question

Comment: @ali, have you tried this answer - its not union all